Привет из детства
Стоит ли оформлять во фразе привет из детства слово "привет" в кавычки?
Спасибо!

• Приветом из детства может быть что угодно:
найденные школьные тетради или давно забытая коллекция значков, зачитанная книжка, обнаруженная в коробке на антресоли, детские фотографии и с ними связанные воспоминания, неожиданная встреча с одноклассником, которого не видел много лет, старый фильм или мультик...
То, что вызывает у нас (чаще всего) положительные эмоции, или удивление, или легкую тоску по ушедшему детству.
Если же привет из детства несет с собой негативное его восприятие, то слово привет обычно произносится с сарказмом.
• Вот книга: Привет из детства (М. Лабковский).
• Вот выставка: Экскурсия «Привет из детства советского ребенка» (Нижний Новгород).
• Вот тексты:
...я увидел хоть и подмокший, но нетронутый брусок щербета, словно привет из детства (А. Моторов).
Внутри самой маленькой коробки лежал привет из детства,  из его, Андрюхиного детства — настоящая почтовая открытка с картинкой, которую он очень любил (О. Мухин).
Весной я неожиданно получила письмо от Мориса, как привет из детства (И. Артамонова).
● В таком контексте кавычки не нужны.


Прямое значение слова, использование в разных ситуациях, в том числе с иронией.
ПРИВЕТ, -а; м. Обращённое к кому-л. выражение дружеского 
расположения, дружеских чувств, доброжелательства. 
Сердечный, искренний п. Пламенный п. Передай родным мой 
п. Друзья шлют тебе приветы. Примите мой п. // Разг. 
Дружеское или фамильярное приветствие, обращённое к кому- 
л. при встрече или расставании. П. всей честной компании! 
С приветом, друзья! Ну я ухожу, п.! С дружеским, 
сердечным, большим и т.п. приветом; с приветом 
(заключительная формула письма). Ни ответа ни привета. Об 
отсутствии ответа, отзыва на чьё-л. обращение, письмо. 
Привет! Разг. Выражение удивления, несогласия, иронии. Я 
не пойду. - П., ведь тебя ждут. Я не понимаю. - П., ну, 
ты даёшь. С приветом, в зн. прил. Разг. Со странностями, 
глуповатый или не совсем нормальный (о человеке). Ты что, 
с приветом?


В негативном смысле кавычки возможны, выбор по контексту. Сравнить варианты:


Привет из детства. Как аукнутся ошибки в общении с ребёнком.⁠⁠
«Приветы» из токсичного детства

Стихотворение нашла! https://www.chitalnya.ru/work/3341586/ Вот такой привет из детства Мою память всколыхнул, Даже жил он по соседству Вася, кличка караул!!!    Здесь можно и КАВЫЧКИ поставить, смысл  явно переносный, А вообще стихов с таким названием много, но хороших нет)      В этой теме  в кавычки можно заключить не словосочетание, а слово привет, если значение отличается от словарного и его надо выделить.
